# How to compare conditions written in a loop in vuejs with value obtained through sessions in php?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In php, we can use if else in loop to check and compare session variables.

How to do the same using vuejs's v-if to compare with php session variable.

```
<span v-if="position.company_enroll_id === <?php var_dump(session('positions'))  ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="text-muted" >Already choose</span>
</span>

{{-- Not enroll --}}
<span v-else>
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#" @click="addRegisterList(company_enroll_id)">Selected</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do with laravel blade and it is recommended to not use vanilla php with blade syntax in laravel.

```
@if(session()->has('positions'))
    <span v-if="position.company_enroll_id === {{ session()->get('positions') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="text-muted" >Already choose</span>
</span>
@endif


{{-- Not enroll --}}
<span v-else>
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#" @click="addRegisterList(company_enroll_id)">Selected</a>
</span>
```

Comment: oh !! Fix it. {{ session()->get('positions') }} a lot of help. thk!!!! :)